# Android library cannot find resources

Tags: java, android

I created an Android library with a custom MyButton class. When I imported the library into another application and instantiated the button, it worked fine and the button showed up.

But when I went to add a background image to the button, everything crashed. I added the image to the drawable folder in res/drawable in my library project, and in my Button class, I set the background image by calling

```
this.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.customimage);
```

where customimage.png was an image in the resources. When I reimported the library and ran the app, I got a runtime error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.mybutton.R$drawable
```

Any idea what I'm missing here? I've been stuck on this problem for a while, and I've done a lot of digging around and tried a lot of solutions to no avail. I'm assuming there is something really minor in my code that I'm missing. Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: So where is your code?

Comment: Did you add the library to the build path?

Comment: did you happen to have any capital letters in your custom image's name?  (Assuming that you didn't actually call it "customimage")

Comment: project structure pls